# If cells contains sum of two cells

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sum

I would like to write a macro which goes through all cells in column and if it finds any formula in cell then it simply ignores this cells and simply 'DO NOTHING'.

I know about HasFormula property in VBA but not really sure it works for cells where I sum two cells simply (for instance, `=C4+C5`). Here is an example:

```
'loop (if the cell has formula then loop ignores that cell

   i = 1
   For i = 5 To 100
   If InStr(1, Sheets("Corporate Detailed").Cells(i, "F"), "+") > 0 Then
      could be also used---'If Sheets("Corporate Detailed").Cells(i, "G").HasFormula = True Then
    Else
        'Do some operations
    End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: `=C4+C5` is a formula and the `.hasformula` should return true. But reverse your if to find those without formulas, doe your things and you will not need the else.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. I thougt VBA only recognizes if it has pure EXCEL FORMULA (for instance, sum, count and etc.).